# Почему не запускается интерпретатор PHP?

Tags: apache, php

Не обрабатывается php код. localhost работает, mod_php подключен. Не обрабатывает даже в *.php файлах

> плюс не мешало бы написать, какая ось

Ubuntu 12.04. Все ставил отдельно, через apt-get.

> Что в конфигурацинном файле Апач написали? Все ли пути прописали правильно? Откройте любой туториал в вебе по настройке Apache c php и проследуйте инструкциям в точности от начала до конца. Потом отпишитесь о результате.

Вот http://habrahabr.ru/post/20736/ 
собственно, дошел до момента, когда нужно вывести phpinfo(); =)
в apache2.conf вроде ничего не прописывал. Только в sytes-available,sytes-enabled(ссыль) и в hosts, когда добавлял виртхост.

sytes-available/myhost.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myhost
    ServerAlias myhost
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /home/pilot114/web
    <Directory /home/pilot114/web>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

В hosts:

127.0.0.1       myhost

Comment: Что в конфигурацинном файле Апач написали? Все ли пути прописали правильно? Откройте любой туториал в вебе по настройке Apache c php и проследуйте инструкциям в точности от начала до конца. Потом отпишитесь о результате.


Comment: плюс не мешало бы написать, какая ось, как именно устанавливалось все. и наверное перевести вопрос на руткод.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Уверены что `mod_php` подключен? кофигурационные файлы пхп есть?
у меня такая фигня была, если апач запускался без флага `PHP5`. У меня оно лежало в `/etc/conf.d/apache`

проверьте еще по команде `ps axf | grep httpd`

у меня это выглядит так:

```
/usr/sbin/apache2 -D DEFAULT_VHOST -D INFO -D SSL -D SSL_DEFAULT_VHOST -D LANGUAGE -D PHP5 -D PERL -D CGI -D PROXY -D PROXY_HTTP -d /usr/lib/apache2 -f /etc/apache2/httpd.conf -k start
```

обратите внимание на `-D PHP5` -- не будет такого -- не будет поддержки `php` в `apache`

Comment: >У меня оно лежало в /etc/conf.d/apache
А у меня в /etc/conf.d/ почему-то нет такого.

команда ps axf | grep httpd выдает:
5222 pts/4    S+     0:00      \_ grep --color=auto httpd
Кажется, я делаю что-то не то.

Comment: в убунте может отличаться немного.

а как выглядит php файл?

Comment: Короче, видимо на каком-то этапе я закосячил конфиги php. Не, апач работает замечательно, мне бы так.
решил "просто" - удалил весь web-сервер (все это:apache2 apache2-mpm-prefork apache2-utils apache2.2-common libapache2-mod-php5 libapr1 libaprutil1 libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libmysqlclient15off libnet-daemon-perl libplrpc-perl libpq5 mysql-client-5.0 mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.0 php5-common php5-mysql) и поставил заново по этой статье: http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/apachemysqlphp

Там все замечательно и последовательно разжевано, пользуйтесь! =)